# How to unescape rails redirect_to's :anchor => "/ui-tabs-1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, anchor

What I want is

```
redirect_to ... :anchor => "/ui-tabs-1" #=> http://....#/ui-tabs-1
```

What I get is

```
redirect_to ... :anchor => "/ui-tabs-1" #=> http://....#%2Fui-tabs-1
```

I want to include the forward slash in my redirect_to (unescaped).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to *include the forward slash* in your redirect to Url?

If yes, you can just *unescape* it

```
require 'cgi'
redirect_to CGI::unescape(create_path_here_with_anchor)
```

else removing the forward slash from anchor makes it work

```
anchor => "ui-tabs-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes

```
redirect_to ... :anchor => '/ui-tabs-1'
```